# POST body for sending a new messages with the Microsoft BotConnector

Tags: android, json, bots, botframework, botconnector

The REST api details the JSON format of the POST body when sending a message, however it's not clear what goes in the fields. Here is the format ...

```
{
  "id": "string",                         // ?
  "conversationId": "string",             // Conversation ID
  "created": "2016-06-22T10:45:48.618Z",  // Current time?
  "from": "string",                       // Username?
  "text": "string",                       // The message to be sent
  "channelData": "string",                // ?
  "images": [
    "string"                              // Image URL?
  ],
  "attachments": [
    {
      "url": "string",                    // Attachment URL
      "contentType": "string"             // ContentType
    }
  ],
  "eTag": "string"                        // ?
}
```

I've flagged the field that I am unsure of. At the moment I send off the requests and get a 500 server error in return. The bot works locally fine using the local bot emulator.

This JSON needs to be built in an Android app.

**EDIT:** Here is the intercepted JSON and response I am sending

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/D0I7X8284zv/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: directline.botframework.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 239
Authorization: BotConnector Ve7jitnSIdE.dAA.RAAwAEkANwBYADgAMgA4ADQAegB2AA.Iy0ZhjLN0QE.e9o7v6n2Xz4.8C7zj2UlOP6202jMEpHqjXVfZxexO5JxzFE7VrRgaXg
Postman-Token: dd7b4c43-84ea-7c38-bd2c-681f6c031eb0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cookie: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
  "id": "SomeId",
  "conversationId": "D0I7X8284zv",
  "created": "2016-06-23T09:05:06.718Z",
  "from": "someusername",
  "text": "annual leave",
  "channelData": "Conv1",
  "images": [],
  "attachments": [],
  "eTag": "blah"
}
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: UserId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 09:06:06 GMT

{
  "message": "failed to send message"
}
```

Comment: Are you using direct API?

Comment: Yeah I'm using the Direct Line REST API

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, text is the message that user sends to bot. I got 500 error when I enable the web chat with direct line API. But it automatically solved after 5 or 6 hours.

By the way according the Microsoft help, They gave me these two options,
Direct Line will return errors in two situations:

1. There is a problem with your message or an internal error in Direct Line
2. Your bot is returning an error message

As you mentioned, in emulator it works fine. so it is because of the message you are passing.

```
Message {
id (string, optional): ID for this message ,
conversationId (string, optional): Conversation ID for this message ,
created (string, optional): UTC timestamp when this message was created ,
from (string, optional): Identity of the sender of this message ,
text (string, optional): Text in this message ,
channelData (string, optional): Opaque block of data passed to/from bot via the ChannelData field ,
images (Array[string], optional): Array of URLs for images included in this message ,
attachments (Array[Attachment], optional): Array of non-image attachments included in this message ,
eTag (string, optional)
}
Attachment {
url (string, optional): URL for this attachment ,
contentType (string, optional): Content type for this attachment 
} 

Conversation {
conversationId (string, optional): ID for this conversation ,
token (string, optional): Token scoped to this conversation ,
eTag (string, optional)
}
```

here with I share C# code, may be that will help you,

```
 private async Task<bool> PostMessage(string message)
        {

            client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BotConnector", "[YOUR BOT TOKEN]");
            response = await client.GetAsync("/api/tokens/");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var conversation = new Conversation();
                response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/conversations/", conversation);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Conversation ConversationInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Conversation)).Result as Conversation;
                    string conversationUrl = ConversationInfo.conversationId+"/messages/";
                    BotDirectLineApproch.Models.Message msg = new BotDirectLineApproch.Models.Message() { text = message };
                    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(conversationUrl,msg);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync(conversationUrl);
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            MessageSet BotMessage = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(MessageSet)).Result as MessageSet;
                            ViewBag.Messages = BotMessage;
                            IsReplyReceived = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return IsReplyReceived;
        }
```

And I created a class with same JSON as follows,

```
public class MessageSet
    {
        public Message[] messages { get; set; }
        public string watermark { get; set; }
        public string eTag { get; set; }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string conversationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string channelData { get; set; }
        public string[] images { get; set; }
        public Attachment[] attachments { get; set; }
        public string eTag { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attachment
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }
    }
```

And for the Conversation,

```
public class Conversation
    {
        public string conversationId { get; set; }
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string eTag { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope this answer will give you a help to solve your problem.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, its good to see source - Is the `Message` class you posted the same as `BotDirectLineApproch.Models.Message` or just made up from a JSON response? If it is, do you have any idea how the `Message` fields get populated? Are all the fields default aside from `text`?

Comment: Also does my bot need to be published to POST messages? My bot is in review at the moment and I can start conversations and download all messages but get 500 only when posting a new message ...

Comment: Message made up from the JSON response.

Comment: I have implemented this code in a test UWP app and it did not work - I still get the 500 error. I have also tried uploading the test C# app to BotConnector ([described here](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#navtitle)) and get the same 500 error.

Comment: Above code is tested in ASP.Net mvc web application. You are getting 500 when you passing message to Bot.. right? But with the bot emulator, do you get the first message when you add  like this, `else if (message.Type == "UserAddedToConversation")
            {
                return message.CreateReplyMessage("Hi Champ, How can I help you?");
            }`

Comment: The bot framework emulator works but this connects to the bot on Azure directly, not via the BotConnector Direct Line API. The problem I find is with the direct line API - POSTing a message using this API returns 500.